# Need suggestions for reliable data broadcasting inside LAN using Java or android

Tags: java, sockets, networking, tcp, udp

We are working on a Android project with the below requirements.

- The application should be able to send data to all the devices which are running our application which exists in the WiFi LAN.
- Some payloads are expected to be of size >= 5MB.
- The data shouldn't be lost and if lost the client should know the failure.
- All the devices should be able to communicate with all other. There will be no message targeted to a specific device instead all the messages should be reached all the devices in the N/W.
- No internet hence no remote server.

**Study we have done:-**

- UDP Broadcasting - UDP doesn't guarantee the message delivery but this is a prime requirement in our case. Hence not an option.
- TCP - TCP guarantees the message delivery but requires the receiver IP address to be known before hand and in our case we need to send the message to all the devices inside the LAN. Hence not a straight option.

**Solutions we are looking into:-**

- A Hybrid approach - Name one of the devices in the N/W as Server. Post all the messages to a local Server. The Server keeps a open socket to all the devices(which have our application) & when there is a message from a device then it routes the message to all the devices. The disadvantages of this approach are,

  - Server having multiple sockets open each per device. But in our case we are expecting devices <=5 in LAN.
  - Server discovery using continuous UDP broadcast.
  - We want to have all the data in all the devices. So if we newly introduce any device into the LAN then that device needs to get all the data from the server.

So my question, have you any time worked on these kind of hybrid approaches? Or can you suggest any other approaches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your hybrid approach is the way to go.

Cleanly split your problem into parts and solve them independently:

- Discovery: Devices need to be able to discover the server, if there is any.
- Select server: Decide which of your devices assumes the server role.
- Server implementation: The server distributes all data to all devices and sends notifications as necessary. Push or pull with notifications does not matter.
- Client implementation: Clients only talk to the server. The device which contains the server should also contain a normal client, potentially passing data to the server directly, but using the same abstract protocol.

You could use mDNS (aka Bonjour or zeroconf) for the discovery, but I would not even recommend that. It often createsmore problems than it solves, and it does not solve your 'I need one server' problem. I would suggest you handcraft a simple UDP broadcast protocol for the discovery, which already tells you who the server is, if there is any.

Select server: One approach is to use network meta data which you have anyway, for example 'use the device with the highest IP address'. This often works better than fancy arbitration algorithms. Once you established a server new devices would use this, rather than switching the server role.

Use UDP broadcast for the discovery, with manual heuristic repeats. No fancy logic, just make your protocol resilient against repeated packets and repeat your packets. (Your WLAN router may repeat your packets without your knowledge anyway.)

You may want to use two TCP connections per client, potentially to two different server ports, but that does not matter much: One control connection (always very responsive, no big amounts of data, just a few hundred bytes per message) and one data connection (for the bulk of the data, your > 5 MB chunks). This is so that everything stays responsive.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @Overmann. I just started implementing a prototype application as a proof of concept. I will post the final status here.

Comment: Cool, looking forward to that. Cool stuff!